# Installation GMLib in Delphi 7 with TChromiun

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, tchromium, gmlib

I try to install GMLib to work  with TChromium browser in Delphi 7.

During the compilation compiler shows this code:

```
TChromium(FWebBrowser).Browser.MainFrame.VisitDomProc(
  procedure (const doc: ICefDomDocument) //compiler higtlights this row
  begin
    FFields.CommaText := GetFieldsName(doc.GetElementById(FormName));
    Finish := True;
  end
);
```

Next compiler writes:

```
[Error]WebControlVCL.pas[513]:Expression expected but 'PROCERURE' found
```

What is the matter?

Comment: As I explained in my blog [here](http://www.cadetill.com/gmlib-google-maps-library-v0-1-9/#english), GMLib with Chromium don't work, sorry